# Al utilizar JWT Service, no me carga el módulo en angular

Tags: angular, jwt

Resulta que quiero verificar cuando un token expira, esto lo estoy haciendo por medio de la librería angular-jwt, pero a la hora de ejecutar la función isExpired(), este no la hace y lo peor es que no manda ningún error a la consola:

```
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
   helper = new JwtHelperService();
   constructor() { }
   isAuthenticated() {
       const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('credentialsKey'));
       console.log(user.accessToken);
       console.log(this.helper.isTokenExpired(user.accessToken));
       return !this.helper.isTokenExpired(user.accessToken);
   }
}
```

Quisiera saber qué es lo que ocurre, me imprime el token, pero no me imprime la respuesta a la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que desde el backend la clave venía encriptada, así que era imposible realizarlo por medio de la librería JWT-Service, pero lo pude solucionar con el uso de un interceptor, realizando la acción justo cuando detectaba el error de expiración (realizando acciones distintas dependiendo si se seleccionó la casilla de Remember Me en el Login):

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // if the token is valid
        }
      }, (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            const data: AuthModel = this.loginService.getCredentials();
            if (data.isRemember) {
              const refreshToken: RefreshModel = {
                refreshToken: user.refreshToken
              }
              this.authService.refreshToken(refreshToken).subscribe((res: any) => {
              });
              this.toastr.info("Credenciales caducadas, actualizando la página...");
              setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.reload();
              },
                1500);
            }else{
              this.toastr.info("Credenciales caducadas, regresando al inicio de sesión...");
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.loginService.logout();
              },
                1500);
            }
          }
        }
      }));
```